# how to prevent jackson from generating pojos on some json properties

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've a peculiar json. In the below json file, I don't want to generate pojos for `j10` & `j11` properties but for the properties inside `j10` and `j11` can have pojos.

Can this be achieved with `jackson` api?

The only reason I want to skip generating pojos is I'll endup creating 30 pojos which doesn't make any sense.

Json file :

```
{
            "jh": [
                {"j10": {
                    "components": [
                        {
                            "name": "InventoryManager",
                            "url": "/atg/commerce/inventory/InventoryManager",
                            "properties": [
                                {
                                    "name": "maxConcurrentUpdateRetries",
                                    "value": "0",
                                    "exclusions": "true"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "CatalogTools",
                            "url": "/atg/commerce/catalog/CatalogTools/",
                            "properties": [
                                {
                                    "name": "queryASAFFabrics",
                                    "value": "skuType=\"ASAF_FABRIC\" AND NOT basicColor IS NULL ORDER BY dynamicAttributes.fabricpriceband, basicColor, dynamicAttributes.fabrictype, dynamicAttributes.asafpattern, dynamicAttributes.asaffabricbrand",
                                    "exclusions": "false"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "loggingDebug",
                                    "value": "true",
                                    "exclusions": "false"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "bots": "true"
                }
            },
                {
                "j11": {
                    "components": [
                        {
                            "name": "InventoryManager",
                            "url": "/atg/commerce/inventory/InventoryManager",
                            "properties": [
                                {
                                    "name": "maxConcurrentUpdateRetries",
                                    "value": "1",
                                    "exclusions": "false"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "CatalogTools",
                            "url": "/atg/commerce/catalog/CatalogTools/",
                            "properties": [
                                {
                                    "name": "queryASAFFabrics",
                                    "value": "skuType=\"ASAF_FABRIC\" AND NOT basicColor IS NULL ORDER BY dynamicAttributes.fabricpriceband, basicColor, dynamicAttributes.fabrictype, dynamicAttributes.asafpattern, dynamicAttributes.asaffabricbrand",
                                    "exclusions": "false"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "loggingDebug",
                                    "value": "true",
                                    "exclusions": "false"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "bots": "false"
                }
            }
            ]}
```

Please do let me know if the question needs some improvements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can modify your JSON (once it has been read) and remove the part from the beginning to { components. Likewise, remove the  { "j11": part. Basically, you can modify your JSON in any way that suits your needs (i.e your POJOs)

Comment: @dsp_user, thanks for the suggestion. json parsing is new to me, could you please pass me some links or code snippet could be of great help.. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated!

Comment: I have no link but it's really simple. Your JSON (once it's been read) is just a normal string. Remove the parts that you don't need and then call ObjectMapper.readValue(yourModifiedJsonString, type);//ObjectMapper.readValue(String , Class<T>)